# In practice, How does one make resultset not equal to NULL?

Tags: java, database, forms, swing, events

Reference an earlier question I had:

[Database scrolling buttons using java forms - Error when calling next method to move cursor up Resultset object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766262/database-scrolling-buttons-using-java-forms-error-when-calling-next-method-to)

In reference to an Answer I had to the above question(see bottom paragraths of this question)

I was wondering - when it is said that you are: 'hiding your variables' - What does this actually mean in practice: Is it in reference to the netbeans generated code event stub which was set as a private function? If so How do you change it to public because I have tried and Netbeans wont let me!

and here is my code:��

```
public void DoConnect( ) {

        try{
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employer";
        String uName = "admins";
        String uPass= "admins";


        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
//        Statement stmt = con.createStatement( );
        stmt = con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );

        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM WORKERS";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );

        rs.next( );
        int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
        String id=Integer.toString(id_col);
        String first= rs.getString("First_Name");
        String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

        textID.setText(id);
        textFirstName.setText(first);
        textLastName.setText(last);
        textJobTitle.setText(job);

        }

        catch ( SQLException err ){
               System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );

        }

    }
```

and the netbeans generated event code stub. inside of which I placed my event code:

```
private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {





        if ( rs.next( )) {

               int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
                String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
                String first = rs.getString("First_Name");
                String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");
                String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

                textID.setText(id);
                textFirstName.setText(first);
                textLastName.setText(last);
               textJobTitle.setText(job);
            }
            else {
                rs.previous( );
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "End of File");
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException err) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
            System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
        }
    }                                       


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Workers().setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

and earlier Answer kindly given to me by a @Uwe Plonus who said the following:

"Your problem is that your ResultSet is null.

Your are hiding your variable rs.

Your code (basically) is:

```
public class Sample {
    ResultSet rs; // is null
    public method() {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.execute(); // here the other rs is hidden
    }
}
```

If you want to make your code working don't hide the variable. Also don't hide the connection.

To get answers faster try to reduce your code and make the example shorter and concentrate on your real problem."

and I said...

"Thanks for your answer . Could you show me specifically ��how to un-null the rs object please"!

and for that matter unhide my variables. and also make the private event stub public??

Please Help!

Comment: In practice, I've never seen a ResultSet that *was* null, unless I didn't get it from Statement.executeQuery(). Sounds like a minor programming error to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following code :

```
public class Sample {
    ResultSet rs; // is null
    public method() {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.execute(); // here the other rs is hidden
    }
}
```

You have two variables:

- one variable called `rs`, declared in the class
- one local variable also called `rs`, declared in the method

So, when you assign something to `rs` in the method, you don't assign anything to the `rs` field, since they're two different variables. If your intention is to initialize the field, the code should be

```
public class Sample {
    ResultSet rs;
    public method() {
        this.rs = stmt.execute(); // there is no declaration here, so rs is the field
                                  // and not a new, local variable
    }
}
```

or simply

```
public class Sample {
    ResultSet rs;
    public method() {
        rs = stmt.execute(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JB. Nice and clear. I understood and now my program works. Should of known better, basic program error. Wow you have a very high reputation I see.